# How to get difference of two csv files by columns and write diff into 3rd file?

Tags: text-processing, csv, diff, file-comparison

I have two csv files like this;

```
422174,XN,20.99,2020-09-01,2022-01-20 20:20:28.613+00
421348,SB,21.99,2021-01-26,2022-01-20 20:20:28.613+00
885176,XN,41.80,2021-11-17,2022-01-20 20:20:28.613+00
881751,SB,12.81,2020-09-01,2022-01-20 20:20:28.613+00
722483,XN,67.50,2020-09-01,2022-01-20 20:20:28.613+00
```

Second file;

```
422174,XN,25.99,2020-09-01,2022-01-21 20:20:28.613+00
667843,XN,22.99,2020-09-01,2022-01-20 20:20:28.613+00
421348,SB,21.99,2021-01-26,2022-01-20 20:20:28.613+00
885176,XN,41.80,2021-11-17,2022-01-20 20:20:28.613+00
881751,SB,12.81,2020-09-01,2022-01-20 20:20:28.613+00
156734,XN,34.50,2020-09-01,2022-01-20 20:20:28.613+00
```

Output should be ;

```
667843,XN,22.99,2020-09-01,2022-01-20 20:20:28.613+00
156734,XN,34.50,2020-09-01,2022-01-20 20:20:28.613+00
```

But the thing is that, I need to compare this two csv files by column1 and column2 only.

For example;

if column1 - column2 of file1.csv = column1 - column2 of file2.csv this shouldn't be considered as difference.

Because last column can be different from file1 but column1 and column2 should be same, which means no difference.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Well, just to be sure , do you want the difference between both files or do you want the lines that are in file2 but not in file1? (According to their column in this case)

Comment: Yes @EdgarMagallon I want the lines that are in file2 but not in file1 according to the column1 and column2, not the whole row.

Comment: I think this is what you need https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/727169/195582

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]; next} !(($1,$2) in a)' file1.csv file2.csv
667843,XN,22.99,2020-09-01,2022-01-20 20:20:28.613+00
156734,XN,34.50,2020-09-01,2022-01-20 20:20:28.613+00
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the great [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-miller/) and a classic JOIN operation, to have unpaired rows from the right file (the second one):

Running:

```
mlr --csv -N join --np --ur -j 1,2 -f input_01.csv then unsparsify input_02.csv
```

you get

```
667843,XN,22.99,2020-09-01,2022-01-20 20:20:28.613+00
156734,XN,34.50,2020-09-01,2022-01-20 20:20:28.613+00
```

Some notes:

- `-N` to set that your csv have no heading
- `--np` to have not paired records
- `--ur` to emit unpaired records from the right file
- `-j 1,2` to set the join fields